# how to remove a file from local commit which is not my last commit

Tags: git, github

I have incorrectly added a zip file to one of my commits which is not the last commit. It is a big file and I get stuck when I try to push these changes to server, because git tries to push the file on remote branch.

How can I remove this particular file.

```
A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> F
```

my remote is at A and I incorrectly added file in commit C and now I'm at commit F.

When I do

`git log --name-only`

it shows me this file [link](http://prntscr.com/cnss63) which I have deleted manually.

Comment: Can you print the result of git status  - does it show this file as deleted?

Comment: here is the result of git status [link](http://prntscr.com/cnubmv) @prabodhprakash

Comment: Okay, 1 more question - for these 5 commits that you are ahead with, could you show the log for the commit that deleted the file and could you please once check that the file is not added back in any of these commit?

Comment: I've a small hack that you can try for this scenario - mark this file/directory as ignored and then you can try to push it again.

Comment: that file was added in the commit before I deleted it manually so when I try to push that commit I get stuck. @prabodhprakash

Comment: Oh, got your scenario now...thinking...

Comment: I have improved your questions for better understanding, so that others can also help. If you think my description is apt, please accept the edit.

Comment: @prabodhprakash approved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124572/discussion-between-prabodhprakash-and-adam-nick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an interactive `git rebase -i` as described here: [Git-Tools-Rewriting-History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). This way you'll create 4 new commits (C', D', E', F') and the original commits will be deleted. If you've not pushed the changes anywhere outside your local git repository then it is okay, otherwise you haven't to do that at all costs!

Comment: i get this error `Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.`

Comment: As the error message says - you have made changes after your last commit. Interactive Rebasing will change your working directory with every commit you'll rebase, so it needs a 'clean' directory. I you don't want to commit your actual changes then you can use `git stash` to save them away and get them back after rebasing is done with `git stash apply` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: it says `No local changes to save`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you have to stage your changes first with `git add *` (as you do before a commit, but this time you'll use stash afterwards).

Comment: same message `No local changes to save`

Comment: Please tell me the output of `git status`!?

Answer (score 0):

git rebase -i HEAD~20  // rebase the last 20 commits

// a list of commits will show

//go to the proper commit and type 'edit' then hit "Enter" on you keyboard

I am assuming you are using nano and not vim

Comment: i am getting this error `Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.`

Comment: Then ether stash or commit them. You can usually see what is going on by doing git status.